# Como conseguir as coordenadas de localização em modo offline

Tags: html5, mobile, aplicação-web, gps

Até onde sei, as coordenadas, latitude e longitude, dependem do hardware GPS e não necessariamente de conexão com Internet ou Dados. Há uma forma de conseguir esses dados através de um browser (aplicação web) em um smartphone com GPS?

Answer (score 1):

Sim, alguns frameworks de criação de aplicaçoes hibridas como o PhoneGap instancia uma classe que utiliza o GPS, WIFI, sinal da operadora e outros. A aplicação chama o método e este pesquisa quais desses recursos pode responder à solicitação, alguns com mais precisão que outros.